# Left Join repetir tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Estou tentando montar um select que tenha o resultado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o select abaixo consigo aparecer o *null* em apenas uma coluna. Como poderia fazer para ele funcionar para as 20? Tenho do item_1 até item_20 e a descrição do item está na tabela de peças, nas ocorrências tem apenas o código dele.

```
SELECT P1.descricao desc1
FROM ocorrencias
LEFT JOIN pecas P1
ON P1.cod_peccin=ocorrencias.item_1 
WHERE ocorrencias.cod = 2
```

Tentei dessa forma com duas colunas, mas não deu certo:

```
SELECT P1.descricao desc1, P2.descricao desc2
FROM ocorrencias
LEFT JOIN pecas P1, pecas P2
ON P1.cod_peccin=ocorrencias.item_1, P2.cod_peccin=ocorrencias.item_2
WHERE ocorrencias.cod = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quem interessar, resolvi da seguinte forma (aqui tem 3 itens):

```
SELECT P1.DESCRICAO AS desc1, P2.DESCRICAO AS desc2, P3.DESCRICAO AS desc3
FROM ocorrencias o LEFT JOIN
     pecas P1
     on P1.cod_peccin = o.item_1 LEFT JOIN
     pecas P2
     on P2.cod_peccin = o.item_2 LEFT JOIN
     pecas P3
     on P3.cod_peccin = o.item_3
where
     o.cod=2
```