# Não exibir linhas null nos resultados de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma consulta em mysql simples

```
SELECT usr_contact FROM $usr_
```

eu utilizo PDO para conectar
esta tabela tem linhas que tem campos vazios
assim

```
-----------------------
|   id    |usr_contact|
-----------------------
|  1234   |    null   |
-----------------------
|  null   |   147852  |
```

na consulta ele cria

```
contact
---
X
---
147852
```

como faço para não exibir os campos vazios no resultado?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IS NOT NULL` o id null O.o?

Comment: @rray "`AutoIncrementProgramming`"?

Comment: @rray não serve, se eu ponho isso  SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id    IS NOT NULL ele só traz as informações nulas, se eu ponho SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE usr_contact IS NOT NULL ele tras tudo mesmo os nulos

Comment: sim, id null pois estou criando uma base de dados diferente que não precisa dos ids pois serão todos o mesmo id

Comment: Um `OR` não resolveria ou tem mais coluna para verificar?

Comment: na verdade, terão muitas linhas com valores em branco, exemplo de agenda de telefone, tem nome exibe, não tem nome não exibe, isso que desejo fazer, ele não exibir as linhas que eu não pedir, ou seja, só exibir as linhas com nome mas não as com nome vazio

Comment: puxa, vacilei feio, quando fiz o campo, não o coloquei como padrão NULL

Comment: Já tentou usar left join? Veja se isso te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116937/left-join-repetir-tabelas/116950#116950

Comment: então @Diego o erro doi na pecinha, esqueci de por null na tabela, agora está funcionando o is not null, mas obrigado.